# Magento : Add Custom Attribute in Bundle Shipment Invoice

Tags: product, magento-1, invoice, bundle

I want to add item number in shipment and order invoice for bundle products. I add `item number` attribue for configrable successfully.

Now I m unable to get sku of parent item, to get item number of bundle products. I try many methods but didnt get perfect solution.

I follow the path:
Mage_Bundle_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice

please any can help me... any suggestions

Thanks.